# Android app keeps receiving notifications

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I have an Android app that can receive notifications via Firebase. These notifications are triggered by user actions on a website. Our API then sends a notification request to Firebase.

Recently however, I have been running into an issue where my app keeps receiving notifications non-stop. This seems to be happening both for direct notifications and topic messages.
At first I thought it was the API being stuck in some sort of loop but this doesn't appear to be the case as it is also happening with notifications I send directly from the Firebase console. My own theory is that Firebase thinks that the notification didn't arrive on the destination device and is therefore re-sending it.

On a side note, the iOS version of my app doesn't appear to have this issue.

My `onMessageReceived()`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Received notification");
    Map data = message.getData();
    try {
        String scope = (String) data.get("scope");
        if(scope == null){
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Received notification with no scope");
            return;
        }

        String senderName = (String) data.get("senderName");
        String notificationMessage = (String) data.get("message");
        SharedPreferences notificationPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS, 0);

        switch(scope){
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_PROTOCOL:
                handleProtocolUpdateMessage(data);
                return; // PROTOCOL notifications are not stored in DB
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_USERSETTINGS:
                handleUserSettingsUpdateMessage(data);
                return; // USERSETTINGS notifications are not stored in DB
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_DEVICE:
                if(notificationPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_DEVICE_NOTIFICATION_FILTER, true)){
                    updateUnreadNotificationCounter();
                    createNotification(scope, senderName, notificationMessage);
                }
                break;
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_INVENTORY:
                if(notificationPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_INVENTORY_NOTIFICATION_FILTER, true)){
                    updateUnreadNotificationCounter();
                    createNotification(scope, senderName, notificationMessage);
                }
                break;
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_JOURNAL:
                if(Application.test(this)){
                    return;
                }else{
                    if(notificationPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_JOURNAL_NOTIFICATION_FILTER, true)){
                        updateUnreadNotificationCounter();
                        createNotification(scope, senderName, notificationMessage);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_SUPPLY:
                if(notificationPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_SUPPLIES_NOTIFICATION_FILTER, true)){
                    updateUnreadNotificationCounter();
                    createNotification(scope, senderName, notificationMessage);
                }
                break;
            case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_SYSTEM:
                if(notificationPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION_FILTER, true)){
                    updateUnreadNotificationCounter();
                    if (Application.test(this)) {
                        createNotification(scope, "A", notificationMessage);
                    } else {
                        createNotification(scope, "B", notificationMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                //If scope doesn't match any known scopes then return
                return;
        }

        saveNotification(data);
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error while parsing notification contents", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code of for better understanding.

Comment: @Raj I added some relevant code.

Comment: ok please post createNotification method's code also and please check that unique notification id passed notify method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated Firebase from 11.0.1 to the latest version, 11.6.1 and the issue no longer seems to occur.